# Applying lambda regex to pandas dataframe and getting correct result back but surrounded in [ ]

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use lambda and regex to extract text from a string in pandas dataframe,  I have regex right and can fill a new column with the right data, but it is surrounded by [ ]?

**Code to build dataframe:**

```
carTypes = {'Car Class Description' : ['A - ECAR - Economy',
            'C - ICAR - Intermediate',
            'D - DCAR - Full Size',
            'E - FFAR - Large SUV - 5 Seater',
            'E1 - GFAR - Large SUV - 7 Seater']}

df_carTypes = pd.DataFrame(carTypes)
```

**Code to apply regex to each row in dataframe and generate and populate a new column with result:**

```
df_carTypes['Car Class Code'] = df_carTypes['Car Class Description'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'^\w{1,2}',x))
```

**Result:**

I get a new column as required with the right result, but [ ] surrounding the output, e.g. [A]

Can someone assist?

Sorry I can't format better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `re.findall` returns a list of string, whose stringification contains the square bracket.

A tip for using pandas: reduce your use of `apply` and explore more into the built-in functions, they are both convenient and fast. Here's one way to do it with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df_carTypes['Car Class Code'] = df_carTypes['Car Class Description'].str.extract('^(\w{1,2})')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the result of `re.findall()` returning a list. You can use `re.search()` and `.group()` to return a string result.

```
df_carTypes['Car Class Code'] = df_carTypes['Car Class Description'].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'^\w{1,2}',x).group())
```

Result:

```
              Car Class Description Car Class Code
0                A - ECAR - Economy              A
1           C - ICAR - Intermediate              C
2              D - DCAR - Full Size              D
3   E - FFAR - Large SUV - 5 Seater              E
4  E1 - GFAR - Large SUV - 7 Seater             E1
```