# Regex to extract substring from pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have following column in a DataFrame.

```py
col1
['SNOMEDCT_US:32113001', 'UMLS:C0265660']
['UMLS:C2674738', 'UMLS:C2674739']
['UMLS:C1290857', 'SNOMEDCT_US:118930001', 'UMLS:C123455']
```

I would like extract the value after UMLS: and store it in another column.
I am trying following lines of code but I am not getting the expected output.

```py
df['col1'].str.extract(r'\['.*UMLS:(.*)]')
```

The expected output is:

```py
col1                                                            col2
['SNOMEDCT_US:32113001', 'UMLS:C0265660']                       C0265660
['UMLS:C2674738', 'UMLS:C2674739']                              C2674738, C2674739
['UMLS:C1290857', 'SNOMEDCT_US:118930001', 'UMLS:C123455']      C1290857, C123455
```

Comment: Does each row of `col1` contain a list?

Comment: yes, col1 has list in all the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.explode` to turn the rows of lists into rows of individual strings. Then, you can use `Series.str.extract` to match the desired regular expression. Finally, you can use `DataFrame.groupby` and `DataFrame.agg` to turn `col1` back into its original form with `col2` as desired:

```py
df = df.explode("col1")
df["col2"] = df["col1"].str.extract(r"UMLS:(.+)")
df = df.groupby(level=0).agg({
    "col1": list,
    "col2": lambda x: ", ".join(item for item in x if item == item)
})
```

This outputs:

```py
                                                col1                col2
0              [SNOMEDCT_US:32113001, UMLS:C0265660]            C0265660
1                     [UMLS:C2674738, UMLS:C2674739]  C2674738, C2674739
2  [UMLS:C1290857, SNOMEDCT_US:118930001, UMLS:C1...   C1290857, C123455
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a different re that I tested at https://regex101.com/

```
UMLS:(\w*)
```

With the following command, I got a new column with the data formatted as you desired:

```
df['new'] = df['input'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"UMLS:(\w*)",x)).apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str,x)))
```

The first .apply() function is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61399659/applying-lambda-regex-to-pandas-dataframe-and-getting-correct-result-back-but-su). The findall function returns a list ([C2674738, C2674739]).

Since you want a string with as many matches as are found, the second apply() function (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306988/column-of-lists-convert-list-to-string-as-a-new-column)) will convert the list into a comma delimited string.

I hope there is a more elegant answer :-)